# GNU sort produces unexpected results when there are an uneven number of spaces between the columns of each line

Tags: sorting, gnu, gnu-sort

```
def  24  word
abc  2   word
```

I write the above data to a file called `tmp` and sort by the first column. As expected, the second line becomes the first:

```
  /tmp/sort: cat tmp
def  24  word
abc  2   word
  /tmp/sort: sort -k1,1 tmp
abc  2   word
def  24  word
```

But when I sort using the third column as the primary key and the first column as the secondary key, the lines are not reordered:

```
  /tmp/sort: sort -k3,3 -k1,1 tmp
def  24  word
abc  2   word

# ^^ WRONG
```

I suspect that this has something to do with the fact that there is 2 spaces between the second and third columns of the first line, and 3 spaces for the second line. Indeed, once I replace one of the 3 spaces of the second line with a non-space character, the sort works correctly:

```
  /tmp/sort: cat tmp
def  24  word
abc  2x  word
  /tmp/sort: sort -k3,3 -k1,1 tmp
abc  2x  word
def  24  word

# ^^ CORRECT
```

Does anyone have an explanation for this behavior?

EDIT: even more bizarrely, the sort works correctly when I specify -n (numeric) for the first column, even though it's not actually a number

```
  /tmp/sort: cat tmp
def  24  word
abc  2   word
  /tmp/sort: sort -k3,3 -k1,1 tmp
def  24  word
abc  2   word

# ^^ WRONG

  /tmp/sort: sort -k3,3 -nk1,1 tmp
abc  2   word
def  24  word

# ^^ CORRECT
```

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the solution: use `-b`

```
  /tmp/sort: sort -b -k3,3 -k1,1 tmp
abc  2   word       # expected: abc < def
def  24  word
```

from the man page:

```
       -b, --ignore-leading-blanks
              ignore leading blanks
```

I suspect that without `-b`, `sort` was treating the excess spaces after the space after the second field as being part of the third field. Hence, the third fields for the two lines were   `word` and  `word`, which are *not* the same. With `-b`, the third fields for both are identical: `word`, and so the first field is the determinant, as desired.